# Rails 7 not rendering controller exceptions at all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a relatively new Rails 7 app, which serves as both an html server for a JS SPA and the api for that SPA.

My issue is that in the development environment, errors from the json API are rendered correctly. That is with the error and trace, etc.
But in production, or when I set `config.consider_all_requests_local = false`, Rails doesn't return any error pages at all. It's just a blank response with the 500 status.

I've tried setting the exceptions_app and routes to no avail.

Here's a small example that shows what I'm talking about.

trips_controller

```
class TripsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    raise StandardError, 'Tripped and fell'
  end
end
```

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "/trip/:error" => 'trips#show'
end
```

and a screengrab from the blank response

[image: blank response page]

versions:
Rails 7.0.3.1
ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233)

[.edit]
As requested, adding the console logs from the server

```
=> Rails 7.0.3.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.6.4 (ruby 3.0.2-p107) ("Birdie's Version")
*  Min threads: 0
*  Max threads: 1
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 88888
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on http://[::1]:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/trip/500" for ::1 at 8888-88-88 88:88:88 -8888
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Pluck (1.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by TripsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"error"=>"500"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 3293)


  
StandardError (Tripped and fell):
  
app/controllers/trips_controller.rb:6:in `show'
```

Comment: A 500 error is "internal server error" which means the app breaks. Your webserver (Puma?) should print something in the logs regarding this error.

Comment: can you please add console logs here ?

Comment: @Maxence, all of what you said sort of true. The "application" doesn't break, the request the application is handling throws an exception. That should - and does in other apps - get handled by Rails exception handler. That is not happening here, and is the cause of my question.

Comment: @AmolMohite I added the server logs from the consoel

Comment: @EricProstko I missread your post. Though I don't understand very well, you say in production you don't get any error, but you have created a 500 which seems to display as such in logs: "Completed 500 Internal Server Error". Do you mean you want to see a fall back page with text and images ? like "You got lost" for a 404 ? In these cases there is a few turotials https://dev.to/ayushn21/custom-error-pages-in-rails-4i43 and the fallback pages must be in "public" folder

Answer (score 0):

Following up on this. I don't remember the specific issue this solved, but this code did solve my problem. We can now render error pages in Production as we do in Development.

I added an ErrorsController under `app/controllers/errors_controller.rb`

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  layout "error"

  def show
    @exception = request.env["action_dispatch.exception"]

    redirect_to error_page
  end

  private

  def error_page
    "/#{supported_error_codes.fetch(status_code, '404')}"
  end

  def status_code
    @status_code ||= begin
                       begin
                         @status_code = @exception.try(:status_code) ||
                           ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.new(
                             request.env, @exception
                           ).status_code
                       rescue => _e
                         @status_code = 500
                       end

                     end
  end

  def supported_error_codes
    {
      403 => "403",
      404 => "404",
      500 => "500"
    }
  end
end
```

And then wired that up in `config/application.rb` with

```
class Application < Rails::Application
    ... 

    config.exceptions_app = ->(env) {
      ::ErrorsController.action(:show).call(env)
    }
    ...
end
```

In this way we are able to "redirect" the user to an error page "served" by the SPA. That is to say, the route "/500" is configured in our SPA's router, not in rails routes, so it "redirects" to the SPA's router as a view and component defined by the javascript.